# Como puedo borrar un objeto de un vector, y luego reorganizar el vector?

Tags: java, object

necesito borrar un objeto de un vector, sin importar la posición, y si el objeto deja un espacio vació, se debe re acomodar el vector hasta dejar el ultimo espacio vació, esto es lo que tengo :

```
public void remove(short pos){
    boolean flag = false;
    for (short posRemove = pos; posRemove < listVuelos.length -1 && !flag; posRemove ++){
        if(listVuelos[posRemove +1] != null){
        listVuelos[posRemove] = listVuelos[posRemove + 1];
        }
        else {
            flag = true;
            listVuelos[posRemove] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor usar un [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)? Así te evitas estos detalles de menor importancia.

Comment: Cuál es el error que presenta y/o inconveniente?

Comment: no se puede usar ArrayList, porque no hemos visto el tema, etonces no se permite, y el inconveniete, es que deja un duplicado

Comment: Por favor: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hola Yeferson. He notado que has estado haciendo varias preguntas últimamente, pero no estás marcando ninguna como aceptada. Si las respuestas te han ayudado, es buena práctica que les des un voto positivo. Y, además, si la respuesta resolvió tu problema, es bueno que lo marques como aceptado (haciendo click en el "check" a la izquierda de la respuesta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tener en cuenta que el tipo de dato `short` los valores por defecto de este es  **0**  y no `null` para realizar la comparación. por ejemplo cuando haces un `short[] arr = new short[10];` todos los valores iniciales de tu arreglo será **0**  . Setear el valor de la posición intercambiada a 0 sería una opción

Teniendo en cuenta el comentario  de @sstan , y lo que dice la documentación [datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) los únicos datos primitivos que se puede comparar con `null` serían String y/o Objetos , lo demás al crear toman un valor diferente de `null`
si su tipo de dato del arreglo es `String` seguir usando `null` en la comparación `if`

```
public void remove(short pos){
boolean flag = false;
 for (short posRemove = pos; posRemove < listVuelos.length -1 && !flag; posRemove ++){
    /* Comparar con 0 , y no con null */ 
    if(listVuelos[posRemove +1]!=0){ /*Si es string sería != null */
        listVuelos[posRemove] = listVuelos[posRemove + 1];
        listVuelos[posRemove+1]=0; /* Setear a 0*/
    }
    else {
        flag = true;
        listVuelos[posRemove] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro que el tipo de `listVuelos` sea `short`. Creo que el `short` era simplemente para uso con el índice de la matriz. Por supuesto, como no podemos ver la definición de `listVuelos`, no podemos saber qué es exactamente.

Comment: Es cierto , tomé en cuenta ese detalle en mi respuesta.